# Where is default `server.socket_queue_size` configured in CherryPy in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy server, which is processing requests using a thread pool of, say, `10` threads.
If I send many requests in parallel (~`200` processes constantly sending), I start seeing in my logs (client side) 3 types of errors:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /my-url 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1095da780>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

```
BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

and

```
('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Why 3 different types, btw?

I suppose I see these errors because there were too many requests sent. 
I adjusted `server.socket_queue_size` to match the number of parallel requests I send, and it started working fine. My server configuration looks like this:

```
cherrypy.config.update({
        'server.socket_port': 8080,
        'server.socket_host': 'localhost',
        'server.thread_pool': 10,
        'server.socket_queue_size': 200
    })
```

However, I'm struggling to find **the default value of `socket_queue_size` set in CherryPy**. How much is it? `cherrypy.config['server.socket_queue_size']` gives me nothing unsell I set this value myself.

So, **what is the default value? How do I determine reasonable `socket_queue_size`?**

Comment: it sounds like this is the value you are looking for --> https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/_cpserver.py#L55